# Error message on fget1

Tags: file, matlab, compiler-errors

I am trying to run the code

```
function [ outStruct ] = loadfile( filename )

fid = fopen(filename,'r');
vector=[];
i=1;
while ~feof(fid)
    line=fget1(fid);
    vector(i)=AnotherFunction(line);
    i=i+1;
end
end
```

But I keep getting the error message 'Undefined function 'fget1' for input arguments of type 'double''.

This whole function is mostly a copy of something we did in class, where it seemed to run fine, so I don't know the problem here.

Comment: `fget1` is mostly a function written by some user, not built-in MATLAB. That's why you are getting that error

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `fgetl`, not `fget1`. Note that the last letter in the first one is an L, while in the second (your version) you've put a one.

Comment: We11 there is my prob1em. Always those simple little things that get me. Thanks.

Comment: @user100620 if this answer solved your issue, accepting it would be a good idea